# Как установить python и pycharm на macos?

Tags: python, macos

Подскажите как корректно установить питон и пайчарм новичку на мак ос

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Python - [скачивается](https://www.python.org/downloads/) с сайта разработчика, но проще и удобнее установить через [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) - проще в будущем управлять зависимостями:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
brew install python
```

PyCharm [скачивается](https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/pycharm/download/#section=mac) с сайта разработчика.

Answer (score 0):

[Как скачать и установить Python на Mac OC](https://pythonru.com/baza-znanij/kak-skachat-i-ustanovit-python-na-mac-oc-x)

[Как установить PyCharm на MacOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PV80vqAaYl8&t=6s&ab_channel=%D0%98%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%98%D0%A2%2F%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%2F%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)